# unleash-android-proxy-sdk not working for Android-Java project

Tags: android, gitlab, feature-flags, unleash

I am trying to set up Feature Flags for my Android GitLab project. I am using [Unleash Android Proxy SDK](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-android-proxy-sdk) for it.
I added dependencies in `build.gradle` file as per the readme, but my code does not seem to find any classes within the SDK. I can only see package names.

I tried multiple things including a clean build, deleting build folders, invalidating caches, try out with a sample applucation; but nothing seems to work.

Does this SDK work only with Kotlin code? Has any one faced similar issues in past?

Answer (score 1):

You add the SDK as a dependency just as if it was Java. Kotlin is designed so it can be used from Java as easily as possible, even if you end up with less pretty code (see interoperation documentation).

It should pull in "kotlin-stdlib" as a transitive dependency automatically. Could it be that you have something blocking the "kotlin-stdlib"?